# Google-Gson Converting JSon to CSV

Tags: java, json

What is the easiest way to convert a Json data to a String at CSV format ?

I haven't read all the api yet but it seems that subclassing the default JSonWriter allows to remove unnecessary character in order to be closer to CSV format.

Does a simpler solution exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May [this link](https://svn.openplans.org/svn/arc/tdw/trunk/src/com/camsys/tdw/util/Serializer.java) help you

in this code `XStream api` is used which is used to convert XML to Object and vice versa.

Comment: Link down! That is the precise reason why we should not post link only answers here!